# Setting up a parameter not associated with a field

Tags: crystal-reports

This is hard for me to explain, so please forgive me.

So I have a formula that returns a specific value which is built into the formula.

I was wondering if there is a way to set up a parameter where the formula can return whatever value is entered into the parameter instead. This way I can easily adjust the value rather than having to go into the formula itself and manually changing the value.

Comment: Could you update the question and add the formula you are currently using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In formula editor, just drag the parameter field into the formula.